# Piece of code looping, and i don't know how to solve it

Tags: discord.py

In my bot, it is meant to detect when someone enters a command in the wrong channel. If someone does, it directs them to the proper channel, but the bot detects it's own message, and loops.

I have tried changing the order in the code and modifying if statements

```
elif str(message.channel) != channel or str(message.channel) != admin_channel:
    if message.content.find(str(commands)):
        print(f"""User {message.author}, entered command {message.content} in the {message.channel} channel!""")
        await message.channel.send(f"""Please enter commands in the #bot-commands channel!""")
```

I expect it to direct them and halt until another message is detected, but it detects it's own message, thus, it loops due to constant update

Comment: That `or` should be an `and`.  What you have is equivalent to `not (message.channel == channel and message.channel == admin_channel)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is somewhere in your code, where client=bot, whatever you named your bot within your code, that will stop it from replying to itself

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #stops bot from replying to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
```